# Finding a root with optimize.root up to arbitrary precision

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

Hej, I am trying to find the root of a function R(mu). Sketch of the code:

```
from scipy import optimize

def R(mu):
    [complicated piece of code]

root = optimize.root(R, mu_0, method='hybr', tol = 10 ** (-10))
```

The function R(mu) depends on another parameter SF that I vary. In this spirit, I want to determine very many roots for different parameters SF. However... When I quasi-continuously change SF I sometimes get very "good roots", that give R(mu_{root}) \approx 10 ** (-7) or even closer to zero. But sometimes I also get not so good approximations to the roots s.t. R(mu_{root}) \in [ 0.01, 0.03]... What is going on here? I want to have "good roots", but this tolerance-parameter does not work as expected...

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your function and its mathematical details. Maybe there doesn't exist a zero for some parameters? As root solves a least-squares problem under the hood, you'll get at least a point that minimises the residual if there's no root. In the meantime, passing the exact derivatives and trying different (good) initial guesses might help.

Comment: Hej Joni, thank you very very much!!! Your hint "giving a better initial guess" was just the hint I needed... I think I ended up in local minima if I had a constant initial guess for varying SF-parameter... However... The problem is solved now. It seems still a little bit unsatisfactory that there seems to be no "neat algorithm" that finds a root on an *arbitrary* interval [a, b], without demanding further that f(a) has the opposite sign than f(b) or sth. like that... However... I close this topic. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. To be fair, such algorithms exist for scalar functions. That's why I was implicitly asking you to show your function :P.

Answer (score 0):

Giving better initial guesses of the root (as joni suggested) solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).